# packing fields of a class into a byte array in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a fast way to convert c# classes into byte array. I thought of serializing the class directly to a byte array using an example I found:

```
// Convert an object to a byte array
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
   if(obj == null)
       return null;
   BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
   return ms.ToArray();
}
```

But the byte array I got contains some other information that are not related to the fields in the class. I guess it is also converting the Properties of the class.

Is there a way to serialize only the fields of the class to a byte array?

Thanks

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to convert the field value of a class into byte array so I can send it out through socket interface.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would serialize the fields of a class to a byte[]:

```
public byte[] ToByteArray()
{
    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(MyInt);
        writer.Write(MyLong);
        writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MyString));
        ...

        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: does successive writes to the `MemoryStream` continue filling the buffer? To empty the stream, I would call `stream.Flush()`?

Comment: also, just to check - you are `using(MemoryStream stream...)` and then before the closing brace, returning `stream.ToArray()`. is it returning a copy of stream contents in an array so the reference to `stream` can be dropped and disposed of properly?

Comment: I really wanted to upvote your answer; however, due to the voting timer, I cannot. I had upvoted but removed it until I had completed an implementation of your answer. If you edit and let me know when you do, I will upvote your answer.   :/

Comment: @dboarman: (re: comment #1) Yes, to my knowledge it does.  MemoryStream wraps a byte[] buffer so calling Flush() doesn't do anything. (re: comment #2) Yes. (re: comment #3) Knowing my answer helped you, or anyone, is good enough for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The formatter does not serialize the properties.
But it does add some meta data. (class full name etc.)

Instead of bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
you can use a function inisde the object that will serialized only the fields

```
bf.Serialize(ms, field1);
bf.Serialize(ms, field2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent member variables from being serialized by marking them with the `NonSerialized` attribute as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject 
{
    public int n1;
    [NonSerialized] public int n2;
    public String str;
}
```

You can even do your own custom serialization for your class. You can read all the information about it at the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx).